# Too many Captchas in my GeckoFx browser (C# Winforms)

Tags: c#, recaptcha, geckofx

I created a custom web browser based on C# Winforms and GeckoFx 45.0.32 to get better functions and specific work optimizations, everything works well but when I (or other user) have to solve some ReCaptcha we gets 5 or even 10 images to solve, every single time, always! This is realy anoying and wasting of time.

This doesn't happen when we use FireFox, just one image in the ReCaptcha or normaly it doesn't ask to solve images.

I already changed the user agent to looks like FireFox:

```
string sUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0";
Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User["general.useragent.override"] = sUserAgent;
```

This works in general (like sites as www.whatismybrowser.com) but have no effect over the ReCaptcha.

What more I have to change in my web browser to be recognized as FireFox? Or to stop to show so many captchas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Try to disable cache and clean the cookies. They are located in "C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Local\Geckofx\DefaultProfile".

```
GeckoPreferences.User["browser.cache.disk.enable"] = false;
GeckoPreferences.User["browser.cache.memory.enable"] = false;
```

2) Double check if there is no bug in your code, that calls a captcha 10 times.

3) Try to change the IP (use VPN, etc).

If that does not help, probably you are getting detected by a browser fingerprint.

Comment: What is "browser fingerprint"? Is possible to change it?

Comment: It is a list of parameters, such as IP, browser version, OS, screen dimentions, canvas, list of plugins and mime-types and many others, that are used to identify your browser among the millions of others. You can try to change some of them, but you never know what exactly will help.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered some clues about the CAPTCHAs here https://www.webnots.com/fix-im-not-a-robot-captcha-issue-in-google-search/, especially the item 7:

> 7. Slowdown Your Clicks If you are not using VPN, proxy and your IP and ISP are good then the most probable cause could be the unusual
>      clicks from you. When you enter the keyword and hit the enter key very
>      fast, Google will match your activity with the automated bots and stop
>      you. So slowdown your mouse clicks and speed and use normal speed to
>      avoid the CAPTCHA message.

So, I think the problem is the user's behavior, in other words, in my opinion if the users solve CAPTCHAs all day long they getting very good in this job and sove the CAPTCHAs very fast, so, the system thinks they are robots and shows a lot of challenges to proof they aren't.
This creates a conceptual problem, the more efficient a person becomes, the more obstacles the CAPTCHAs create. And the big deal is to find the best balance between work speed and obstacles created by the CAPTCHAs.